# MS SQL - Aging Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help as I am stuck with this!! :/

I have 5 columns that I select in a query and last 2 are derived/calculated

```
Date | Account | Symbol | Type | User | AgeKEY | Age |
```

where KEY is concatenated (Account+Symbol+Type+User)

How do I look back 1 year into history and calculate the Age of the record? Age is the continuous # of business days that the AgeKey appears in history

Aging Logic Example -

```
11/3 KeyExists hence Age = 1

11/4 KeyExists hence Age = 2

11/7 KeyExists hence Age = 3 (note over weekend ages only by 1 day)

11/8 KeyDoesntExist

11/9 KeyExists hence Age = 1 (counter restarts from 1 if this happens)
```

Comment: what does 11/3 KeyExists mean?

Comment: your question is unclear, explain the logic clearly

Comment: It's not really an unclear question... It's an islands and gaps problem with business days. I guess one way you could do it is with a function that gets the min/max dates from the table, finds all the business days between those dates (not a weekend or a public holiday, but you'd need a table full of public holiday dates for this), then left join it to the original table and compare.

Comment: But how would that account for counting the occurrences of the Key? @ZLK

Comment: @vkp means that the Key which is a concatenation , appears on 11/3 thus the record Age =1, if the same appears the next business day then the Age =2 and so on..

Comment: Well, a left join to your table would create nulls where there's no match on the date. An answer _similar_ to the below given answer might work, but in the CTE you'd change `DATEADD(day,-1 , tab.dt)` to a function that works out the previous business date (e.g. create a function `dbo.fn_lastBusinessDay(tab.dt)`, which takes a date input and spits out the last business day before that date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with T-SQL loop (it reads data from tab table and inserts to tab_result):

```
create table tab 
(dt date, id int);

insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-12,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-10,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-9,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE()),3);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-6,GETDATE()),3);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-5,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-4,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE()),1);

create table tab_result 
(dt date, id int, age int);

DECLARE @id INT, @dt date, @prevId INT=NULL, @prevDt date=NULL,  @age int

 DECLARE CurName CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
 FOR
    SELECT  id,dt
    FROM    tab
    ORDER BY id,dt
 OPEN CurName


 FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @id, @dt
 set @age=0;
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        if (@prevId<>@id or @prevDt <> DATEADD(day,-1, @dt))
                set @age=1;
            else
                set @age=@age+1;   
        insert into tab_result values (@dt, @id, @age )

        set @prevId=@id
        set @prevDt=@dt
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @id, @dt

    END

 CLOSE CurName
 DEALLOCATE CurName

select * from tab_result order by id, dt;
```

with plain sql it would be something like below (id in the example is your key):

```
create table tab 
(dt date, id int);

insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-12,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-10,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-9,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-8,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE()),3);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-6,GETDATE()),3);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-5,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-4,GETDATE()),1);
insert into tab values(DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE()),1);

with x as ( 
select tab.dt,
    tab.id, 
    case when prev.dt is not null then  1 else 0 end  as exists_on_prev_day 
    from
    tab left outer join tab prev on (tab.id=prev.id and DATEADD(day,-1 , tab.dt)= prev.dt)
)
select id,dt, 
(select 
  -- count all records with the same id and date less or equal date of the given record
 count(*) from x x2 where x2.id=x.id and x2.dt<=x.dt
 -- (tricky part) we want to count only records between current record and last record without "previous" record (that is with exists_on_prev_day flag = 0)
  and not exists (select 1 from x x3 where x3.id=x2.id and x3.dt>x2.dt and x3.dt<=x.dt  and x3.exists_on_prev_day=0 )) age 
from x
order by id, dt;
```

result:

```
    id  dt                  age
1   1   19.11.2016 00:00:00 1
2   1   21.11.2016 00:00:00 1
3   1   22.11.2016 00:00:00 2
4   1   23.11.2016 00:00:00 3
5   1   26.11.2016 00:00:00 1
6   1   27.11.2016 00:00:00 2
7   1   28.11.2016 00:00:00 3
8   3   24.11.2016 00:00:00 1
9   3   25.11.2016 00:00:00 2
```

Comment: Thank you..will give this a try !!

Comment: The query runs for a very long time and returns no results with my columns..is that because I am creating a key on the fly ?

Comment: yep. You can try to optimize above query by creating temporary table BUT it is probably not the best solution for your problem as it has to count all records before given records. Event with proper indexes it will be slow. It would be much faster probably by just using T-SQL and calculating the age in the loop.

Comment: Is there an example you can show me using TSql to programmatically get the results? We can use the given example here as a sample table dbo.tab ..thanks !

Comment: I have added to the answer solution with TSQL loop.

Comment: Thanks Arturro ! I have added an additional condition for it to not age over the weekend                                                                                       if DATEPART(DW, @dt) in (1,7)
set @age=@age+0; 
else
set @age=@age+1; Every time I run this it re-calculates age for records and appends to the results table. Is there a way to modify this so that it picks up only records for which age is not calculated ? Thanks !